# .append() removes added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append table rows to an existing table.

This is how my table is structured:

```
<div id="productListContainer">
    <table id="productListTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        #
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Product Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Price
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Quantity
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

With the following function I am trying to append a new table row:

```
function(data) {
                if (data.productAdded !== "undefined") {
                  $("#productListTable tr").append().html(data.productAdded);
                }
              }
```

Which successfully appends one row. However, if I select a different item which triggers the same function, then the added table row will be overwritten with the new one.

I am using this function within an ajax call as the success message.

'data' is a JSON object which contains productAdded which itself is the table row as a string.

Comment: If you're adding a new row, you should be calling `append()` on `$('#productListTable')` and not `$('#productListTable tr')`

Comment: see Rocket's answer, the way you used append() is not ideal

Comment: What exactly does `data.productAdded` contain?

Comment: What are you trying to append, and were do you want to append it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is append a row to the body of the table I assume.  For this you'll need to do this -

```
$("#productListTable tbody").append(html_string);
```

Your `html_string` will need to contain all the necessary `<tr>` and `<td>` elements to match up with your table's header.

References -

- `.append()` documentation  - http://api.jquery.com/append/
- [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hHGat/12/)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `.append()` with no parameters, doesn't append anything, and returns the original jQuery object.  So, when you call `.html()` you're replacing the `<tr>`'s contents.

It should be:

```
$("#productListTable tr").append(data.productAdded);
```

**EDIT**: That would append to the `<tr>` inside the `<thead>`.  I assume you want to append to the `<tbody>`.

```
$("#productListTable tbody").append(data.productAdded);
```

**EDIT 2**: When appending to a table, you need to make sure you have a `<tr>` and the right number of `<td>`s in your string.

Comment: This actually appends a row to the header `<thead>` of the table.  I'm not convinced that this is what the OP is trying to do...

Comment: @Lix: I don't know what the OP is trying to do, but you're right.